# How can I make a collision between 2 images on processing

Tags: processing

I'm trying to make a simple game and I have a problem. 
I program on processing and the language is Java.
The principle of my game is a sushi which eat octopus ✌ 
I have an image of a sushi and others images of octopus which move on my screen. But I don't know how I can say if the image of sushi touch one of the images of octopus the image of octopus touched must disappear. 
Do you have any solution to help me ??

Comment: Without providing any code which you have worked on, it will be difficult to answer your question. Consider adding relevant code.

Comment: But I haven't any code to illustrate this problem. The only code that I have is my sushi which move and my octopus which move too. Is it interesting to answer me ??

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) is a tutorial on collision detection in Processing.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Looks pretty neat

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the bounds of the images intersect. Meaning, is the top of the sushi below the top of the octo, but but above the bottom of the octo? If so, is the left side of the sushi 'above' (=higher x value) the left side of the octo, but 'below' the right side? The code below shows how you can implement this.

[image]

```
a = sushi_image
b = octo_image

if(  (a.x > b.x && a.x < (b.x + b.width) )// left bound of a is between bounds of b OR
     ||  ((a.x+a.width) > b.x && (a.x+a.width) < (b.x + b.width)))// right bound of a is between bounds of b
  {
   if((  a.y > b.y && a.y < (b.y + b.height)) // top bound of a is between bounds of b OR
        ||  ((a.y+a.height) > b.y && (a.y+a.height) < (b.y + b.height)) )// bottom bound of a is between bounds of b
      {
        // images intersect
      }
   }
```

Comment: Okay I think I understand.. But do you think a Boolean variable can help, for example if I say : 
Boléean collision = false;
If (sushi.x+sushi.y==groupe.x+groupe.y){
Bolean = true;
}
If(boléean == true){
Effacer();
}
void effacer(){
....;
}